# Java : No matter which method I use, I cannot round a double to 4 decimals

Tags: java, rounding

I need to round some Doubles to 3 to 4 decimals. I tried 3 different methods, none of them work.

For most of the double I have, it works, but I keep having such doubles anyway :

- 0.12919999999999998
- 0.12365000000000001
- 36371.922099999996

I tried the following methods so far :

```
-- 1
(double) Math.round(someDouble * 10000) / 10000

-- 2
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
twoDForm.format(someDouble);

-- 3
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(someDouble);
bd = bd.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Does anyone have the magic solution I am looking for :) ?

Thank you !

NOTE : 
Here is the full code :

```
// Processing
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < loopSize; i++) {
            process();
        }
        // end timer
        long absTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
        double absTimeMilli = absTime * 1e-6;


        DecimalFormat t = new DecimalFormat("###.####");

        context.setTotalTime(Double.valueOf(t.format(absTimeMilli)));
        context.setUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.setMeanTime(Double.valueOf(t.format(absTimeMilli / Const.BENCH_LOOP_COUNT)));
        context.setExecPerTimeUnit(Double.valueOf(t.format(loopSize / (absTimeMilli*1e-3))));
```

Comment: can you add the output for the 3 methods you have tried ? and tell us what you exactly expect?

Comment: It is hard for me to provide outputs as these are execution time in milliseconds(benchmarking). So I am expecting different values everytime. 
I exepect to have a round up to 4 decimal to every possible double I can have !

Comment: The `BigDecimal`way works perfectly well with the `Double`s you seems to have problems with. Unless the numbers are different but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Actually, the output is very similar for all three methods. I have unrounded double when they are of such format : "xx.000000000000001" or "xx.314339999999999998"

Comment: With the numbers provided I get the following results with method 2: [0.1292, 0.1237, 36371,9221]. How is that not correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing the result **back** into a `double` type (your first example hints that you are), then this will happen. Double cannot store some numbers.

Once you have rounded, store the result in a `BigDecimal` or a `String`.

**Updated - see comments below**

May have misunderstood your comment, but something like this.

```
// this.totalTime += (1.0/someInteger)*myValue

BigDecimal ratio = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(someInteger));
totalTime = totalTime.add(ratio.multiply(myValue));
```

Comment: Let me try this methods. It needs time to run, i'll provide the output when finished :)

Comment: You must put the result straight into a BigDecimal or String and keep it there. The minute you convert it back to a `double` (or `Double`, `Float`, `float`), you may lose the real number.

Comment: Ok, I am implementing this right now. I'll give you the result when I'm done with it, thanks :)

Comment: The problem I have now, is that I have to do some arithmetic operations with them, and therefore obtain 0.0000 everytime. I need to do the following  :

this.totalTime += (1.0/someInteger)*myValue. 

Considering that totalTime and myValue are both BigDecimals. This was my implementation when I was using doubles. How can i properly alter this to use BigDecimals ?

Thanks

Comment: I've added example to answer. BigDecimal is more long-winded, but it will keep your precision and has all the operations that you need. Each operation returns you a new BigDecimal. It also pre-defines some simple numbers like ONE.

Answer (score 1):

```
double val = 2.33333333;
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.####");
```

Try this.

Comment: I had the same thought, but does it round or just truncate?

Comment: Both formats work, the problem isn't the formatting but probably the way he handles it further down the line.

Comment: This doesnt work (i provided my code with your solution in the NOTE)

Answer (score 1):

A double cannot represent all possible decimal values due to the limitations in floating point representation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point for more info or just google "floating ponint precision problem"). So if you need to process the rounded values simply store them in a BigDecimal, round it and keep working with that instead of going back to a double.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i know so far ... to round a double you should use BigDecimal like this:

```
double yourDouble = 0.123456789;
int scale = 3;
double yourRoundedDouble = new BigDecimal(yourDouble).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

the result would be : `0.123`.

note that "scale" is the number of digits you want to have after the point.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you looking for, I do these sort of calculations like this

```
double p=36371.922099999996;

p=Math.round(p *10000.0000)/10000.0000;

System.out.println(p);
```

and I get 36371.9221

Try it